# Normalize numbers for stats

Tags: javascript, statistics, normalize

I'm trying to make a simple daily follower stats like the screenshot below.

[image]

And here's the code I'm using.

```js
const normalize = ({ min, max, number }) => {
  return parseFloat((((number - min) / (max - min)) * 100).toFixed(2))
}

const followers = {
  '03-23-2022': 2115,
  '03-24-2022': 2128,
  '03-25-2022': 2175,
  '03-26-2022': 2195,
  '03-27-2022': 2215,
  '03-28-2022': 2206,
  '03-29-2022': 2258
}

const numbers = []
for (const day in followers) {
  const stats = followers[day]
  numbers.push(stats)
}
const min = Math.min.apply(null, numbers)
const max = Math.max.apply(null, numbers)

for (const day in followers) {
  const activity = followers[day]
  const percent = normalize({ min, max, number: activity })
  console.log({ day, activity, percent })
}
```

As you can see on the console log the normalize function returns 0 for the minimum number and that's why nothing is visible on the site.

What I'd like to do is I want to get some meaningful numbers from the normalize function to be able to show the stats in a more readable style. How do I do that?

Comment: It's actually Twitter follower activities. It'd be different each day.

Comment: What about showing "number of followers gained or lost" on each day?

Comment: Yeah that sound might be interesting. I’ll think about that if I couldn’t find any response to the issue I’ve mentioned in the question.

Comment: There's a good reason you get zero for the first item.  The first item is the lowest (the "min").  In the algorithm, `(number - min) / something` which is `(min - min) / something` == 0.

Comment: Yeah I think it's a standard normalization algorithm but I don't know how to update that to fit my needs.